# Why doesn't my Azure WCF service ever go from Busy to Ready?

Tags: c#, wcf, azure

I have a working WCF service and worker role that I have been debugging locally on the Azure Development Fabric. All is well, but now that I'm trying to deploy it to the cloud in a staging environment, I'm seeing some weird issues.

1. My worker role, which is infinitely more complex than the service, works fine. It goes from Initializing -> Busy -> Ready.
2. My service role, however, goes from Initializing -> Busy and then the status never changes again.

I have read a few articles about Initialize -> Busy -> Stopping loops, but this is not the behavior I'm seeing. In fact, when I try to use IntelliTrace, I can't access any logs for the service because it never enters the Unresponsive status. I am able to access logs for the successfully-loaded worker role.

How am I supposed to resolve this issue if I can't see any logs or attach a debugger to figure out what's going on? Again, this service works absolutely fine on my local environment.

And before anyone suggests it, I have already done the following:

1. Check the `DiagnosticsConnectionString` and make sure it is connected to my storage account
2. Enable IntelliTrace on the deployment.
3. Check all referenced assemblies to make sure non-.NET assemblies are "copy to local = true"

It sure would be great if Azure exposed some kind of console so that I could see what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Later this year, you'll be able to use Remote Desktop to connect in and see what's going on.

For now, you can contact support, and they should be able to help.

Typically, "Busy" is the state you're in while you're still executing code in OnStart().  Is there any chance your OnStart() implementation isn't returning?  (Or perhaps some constructor?)

Comment: I'm only executing a single line of code...it's a RouteTable.Routes.Add()--do you know if that's forbidden on Azure?

Comment: Nope, that should work, but that's most likely in Global.asax.cs somewhere (not in OnStart() in WebRole.cs), right?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, when Azure starts playing blackbox in the production, this is caused by the **problems with configuration**. One of the possible reasons - config section is recognized on your local machine, but is not available on Windows Azure Guest OS.

In this case your role will not even have a chance to say something to IntelliTrace or any logger (it's not loaded).

For example, if you have uri config section in your web.config, then it might work locally, but will cause Azure to freeze web deployment in production. Fix (in this case):

add following line to configuration/configsections:

```
<section name="uri" type="System.Configuration.UriSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
```

Your case might be different. Just look for any uncommon configs or cases, where schema might be unknown to Azure Guest OS you are running against.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and ended up starting with a blank project. Getteing it to run in the cloud. Added a few lines, deploying.

Eventually (after 10 deployments... do you know how long that takes???) I got it working... an the cause was in the config file. I didn't trace it down to one line though.

Contacting support would be the right thing to do, as smarx suggests.